# create empty files with same directory structure as reference directory

Tags: linux, cp

I have a `Dir1` with multiple subdir and files inside it. I intend to copy the `Dir1` to `Dir2` so that all the files in it will be just empty files but with same file name as Dir1.

Then I intend to push the Dir2 to github to explain example data-structure  and filenames to users.

Is there a command to copy files in a way just to destination files are empty but with same filename?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or more complicatedly but with a single filesystem pass (for even more portability `~` should be written as `$HOME`)

```
find . \( -type d -exec mkdir -p "~/elsewhere/{}" \; \
  -o -type f -exec touch "~/elsewhere/{}" \; \)
```

The complexity here is that of Boolean logic (which may be of some benefit to learn) and precedence (also good to know) and how `find` implements these concepts with an implicit AND between the `-type` and subsequent action, and OR making an appearance as `-o`.

Comment: While abstruse one-liners are impressive in their own way and certainly display meritorious mastery of complex shell (or other) incantations, I have opted to increasingly err on the side of simplicity and readability.  That said, if the file structure being replicated is _fantastically_ complex, a single filesystem pass would be the superior option.

Comment: Depends on personal background, some people think in branches, others in sequences. If a once-off project then one command is easier to type, but to be reused and maintained, discrete steps are cleaner.

Answer (score 12):

With GNU coreutils (e.g.. on non-embedded Linux or Cygwin), it's as simple as

```
cp -a --attributes-only Dir1 Dir2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /path/to/oldroot
find . -type d -exec mkdir -p \"/path/to/newroot/{}\"\;
find . -type f -exec touch \"/path/to/newroot/{}\"\;
```

Comment: the above command is throwing error. `find: missing argument to `-exec'`

Comment: @learnningprogramming In addition to the syntax error, the double quotes are neither necessary nor desirable.